# Create Dynamic Cosmos DB Collection in Spring Boot App at Runtime

Tags: spring, azure-cosmosdb

How to create a dynamic Cosmos DB collection in Spring Boot app at runtime?

Tried everything mentioned in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb).

Comment: It's more helpful to post the code you used to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you have `dynamic.collection.name` property in your
  properties file.
- Also to parse the SpEL our application will require
  expressionResolver bean. So annotate your application class with
  `@DependsOn("expressionResolver")`

Comment: CODE RED . CONNECT . SOS