# Read Cosmosdb container name dynamically inside annotation (Spring-boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

In my case, all my lower env cosmos db containers are residing in one database, their names start with the environment followed by the actual container name. How to pass the container-name dynamically in an annotation?

I understand that we cannot use a spring expression directly inside any annotation other than @Value. How to proceed further in such scenarios

[image]

Comment: It can solved using SpringEL  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329590/create-dynamic-cosmos-db-collection-in-spring-boot-app-at-runtime

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I want to be able to set this `containerName` property inside the annotation `@Container` dynamically because it will come from a configuration `.yml` file.